# Fetch session cookies are not sent on firefox

Tags: php, ajax, firefox, cookies

I have an application that makes ajax requests. There is no CORS involved. The ajax is on the same origin. I am using the fetch API. Everything works fine in Chrome. In Firefox 52 it does not work (but it is working on the last versions of firefox).

The session cookie does not seem to be sent in the request, so I have a 302 redirection to the login page.

Again, I am on the same origin, an example of an ajax request that redirects on FF 52 :

```
fetch('/users')
```

Proof :

[image: 1]

If a include the credentials it is working :

```
fetch('/users', {credentials: 'include'})
```

Is this a known issue on FF 52? I can't find information about that on the doc.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specification changed in August 2017, so some browsers from before/around that time still need what is now the implicit default, to be explicitly specified.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API#Differences_from_jQuery:

> fetch() won’t send cookies, unless you set credentials: 'same-origin'.
>
> In August 2017, the spec changed the default credentials policy to 'same-origin'. The following browsers shipped and [sic] outdated native fetch, and were updated in these versions:
>
> - Firefox version 61.0b13.
> - Safari version 12.
> - Chrome version 68.
>
> If you are targetting older versions of these browsers, be sure to include credentials: 'same-origin' init option on all api requests that may be affected by cookies/user login state.